# Entity Framework - tabelas não foram criadas

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Estou seguindo uma apostila de Entity Framework, criei as classes:

```
public class k19Context : DbContext
    {
        public k19Context() : base("k19Context")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Professor> Professores { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Turmas")]
    public class Turma
    {
        public int TurmaId { get; set; }

        public int Vagas { get; set; }

        public Professor Professor { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }

    }

[Table("Professores")]
    public class Professor
    {
        public int ProfessorID { get ; set ; }

        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set ; }

        public Endereco Endereco { get ; set ; }
    }

[Table("Alunos")]
    public class Aluno
    {
        public int AlunoID { get; set ; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30), MinLength(3)]
        public string Nome { get; set ; }

        public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int Idade { get; set; }

        public Endereco Endereco { get ; set ; }
    }

[Table("EnderecoPorAnotacao")]
    public class Endereco
    {
        public int EnderecoID { get; set; }

        public string Logradouro { get; set ; }

        public int Numero { get; set ; }

        public string CEP { get ; set; }
    }
```

Executei o projeto, estou usando o asp net, e somente o banco foi criado, as tabelas não foram criadas. O que aconteceu? Estou usando o SqlServer.

Tentei alguns comandos: `Enable-Migrations`, `Update-DataBase`. Depois tentei passar dados à entidade:

```
public class Teste
    {
        public void Metodo()
        {
            Aluno aluno = new Aluno();

            aluno.DataDeNascimento = DateTime.Now;
            aluno.Endereco = new Endereco();
            aluno.Endereco.Logradouro = "rua teste";
            aluno.Endereco.Numero = 100;
            aluno.Endereco.CEP = "123";
            aluno.Idade = 18;
            aluno.Nome = "fulano";

            k19Context contexto = new k19Context();
            contexto.Alunos.Add(aluno);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Porém o banco continua sem tabelas.

Aqui está o web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Configuration.cs:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<EntityFrameworkTestes.k19Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(EntityFrameworkTestes.k19Context context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
```

Algo mais que preciso acrescentar?

Comment: A sua connectionString (k19Context) faltou colocar na sua pergunta?  e também tem coisas faltando ...

Comment: Vou colocar, o que mais está faltando? Talvez eu não tenha feito isso que está faltando.

Comment: Coloque a connectionStrings que vou verificar

Comment: Na verdade não fiz a connectionString. Já editei o post. O banco foi criado, só as tabelas que não.

Comment: O seu migration não está habilitado: `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;` deveria ser `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` para funcionar `Enable-Migrations, Update-DataBase`

Comment: No seu arquivo de configuração não está presente a configuração de conexão por isso também não vai fazer nada!

Comment: Eu já fiz esses comandos Enable-Migrations, Update-DataBase. "configuração de conexão" você está falando da connectionString?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51769/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-heyjoe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu `Web.config` não possui uma *connection string*:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MeuSistema;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Esta é válida para o Microsoft SQL Server Express. Normalmente, projetos em ASP.NET MVC vêm com um banco de dados LocalDb criado para você em `App_Data` (o arquivo normalmente fica oculto no Solution Explorer).

Answer (score 1):

Está tudo certo ate onde vc fez, agora falta vc dar os comandos:

```
'add-migration nome_da_migration'
```

e outro

```
'update-database',
```

depois vai ate a janela do SQL Server Object Explorer clica com o botao direiro do mouse no Banco de Dados e da um Refresh. Vai aparecer o Banco de Dados criado e suas tabelas.